# MySQL Server Community Version (FTS)

Tags: mysql

Does it have full text search capabilities? While there is ample documentation on FTS functionality I don't see anything in it that suggest whether the free version (community)  does or  does not.

Comment: You haven't bothered to look at the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Answer (score 0):

> Does [MySQL Server Community Edition] have full text search capabilities?

To the best of my knowledge, this feature is currently included in all editions of MySQL (since at least version 5.5).